# Ошибка minSDK(API 23, N preview) != deviceSDK(API 17)

Tags: android

Недавно начал учить андроид и возникла такая ошибка, когда я пытаюсь запустить проект на своем телефоне или эмуляторе. При этом в проекте выставлено "minSdkVersion 15". Режим отладки включен, драйверы установлены.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поставьте `targetSdkVersion = "23"`, а не `targetSdkVersion = "N"`

Comment: и compileSdkVersion 23 тоже на всякий случай